# Creating ordered tables in cassandra (Highscores)

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to create a table that will contain highscores.
Currently the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE speedruns (
  level text, 
  user text, 
  time int, 
  PRIMARY KEY(level, user)
);
```

I'd like to be able to do list the top top 10 speedruns ascending the time and limiting by 10.
If I understand correctly you can only order by a column if it's a primary key? What would be the correct way of achieving a table that has this structure and allows me to perform those kind of operations?

Answer (score 2):

You can order by clustering column so you would have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE speedruns (
  level text, 
  user text, 
  score int,
  time int, 
  PRIMARY KEY(level, score, user)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score DESC);
```